# Type mismatch while using allCatch opt

Tags: exception, scala

In order to avoid Java exceptions I'm using Scala's exception handling class.

However, when compiling the following snippet:

```
 import scala.util.control.Exception._

 val cls = classManifest[T].erasure

 // Invoke special constructor if it's available. Otherwise use default constructor.
 allCatch opt cls.getConstructor(classOf[Project]) match {
   case Some(con) =>
     con.newInstance(project) // use constructor with one Project param
   case None =>
     cls.newInstance // just use default constructor
 };
```

I receive the following error:

```
 error: type mismatch;
    [scalac]  found   : java.lang.reflect.Constructor[_]
    [scalac]  required: java.lang.reflect.Constructor[_$1(in method init)] where
              type _$1(in method init)
    [scalac]     allCatch opt cls.getConstructor(classOf[Project]) match {
    [scalac]                                    ^
    [scalac] one error found
```

What's going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't get this error. What Scala version are you using? Can you provide a _full_, compilable, example of code that gives this error?

Comment: The code above is isolated almost completely to it's own function. Regardless, I'll post a full *compilable* piece of code tomorrow showing the error. And I'm using Scala 2.9 (need to check exact version).

Comment: @Daniel your code may differ in how cls is typed. I believe the problem happens only if is an existential Class[_], not when it is fully typed. Class.forName("..") and not classOf[SomeKnownClass]. Or type ascription to force the existential.

Comment: In my case, `val cls = classManifest[T].erasure` and T is a type param on the class owning the function.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the code above. Once I get to my desktop I'll get a full running piece of code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type inference scheme has gotten confused by the types available--specifically, by the type of cls.  If we write generic code:

```
def clser[A](cls: Class[A]) = allCatch opt cls.getConstructor(classOf[Project])
```

then it works perfectly okay.  But you're probably doing something else--I can't tell what because you didn't provide the code--and this results in a mismatch between the expected and actual types.

Answer (score 2):

I have no explanation, but a much shorter example which I hope pinpoint where the problem occurs. I think it is not related at all to exceptions, nor to reflection. Whether this behavior is an arcane but correct consequence of the specification or a bug, I have no idea.

```
val untypedList : List[_] = List("a", "b")
val typedList : List[String] = List("a", "b") 
def uselessByName[A](a: => A) = a
def uselessByValue[A](a: A) = a
```

`uselessByName(untypedList)` fails with the same error as your code. The other combinations do not. So combination of a method with a generic call-by-name argument, called with a parameter  of a generic with an existential type.

`uselessByName[List[_]](untypedList)` works, so I guess if you call explicitly `opt[Constructor[_]]` it might work too.

Comment: Prior to you answering this, I explored this a bit. I can do allCatch[Constructor[Project]] explicitly but not allCatch[Constructor[_]]. I didn't try type params on opt.

Answer (score 0):

My currently solution is to cast the constructor explicitly.

`cls.getConstructor(classOf[Project])` becomes `cls.getConstructor(classOf[Project]).asInstanceOf[Constructor[Project]]`.

I'm still wondering about the actual error and if there are better ways to resolve it -- so I'm going to leave this open.

Comment: This "workaround" only works if you want a constructor that takes the same object you're constructing, namely `Project`.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you also tell us what the inferred type for `cls` is?